# id (used by javascript) not working when used with div and div has image coming on after the other

Tags: javascript, css

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = changeImage;
//By E.
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById(myImage);

    //Here you must set the image's address you want to appear after the 10 seconds.
    function toImage2() {
        image.src = "image2.jpg";

        //And after 250 seconds, call the first image again.
        setTimeout(toImage1, 10000);
    }

    function toImage1() {
            image.src = "image1.jpg";

            //10 seconds have passed, so call the second image.
            setTimeout(toImage2, 10000);
        }
        //After 10 seconds, the toImage2() function is called.
    setTimeout(toImage2, 10000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myImage" style="background-image: url(image1.jpg);  width: 100%; height: 100px; ">lalal <br>dsdf <br>
    add more 
    <br>more <br>more 

</div>
```

Image is not changing :/
new to css ,html and javascript , need help

Comment: `myImage` should be in quotes

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `var image = document.getElementById(myImage);` to `var image = document.getElementById('myImage');`

Furthermore, your 'image' is really the background on a div element, so instead of assigning the 'src' (a property of an image, and not a div), you need to assign the style background-image. `image.style.backgroundImage= "url(/path/to/image.jpg)"` will work, as it's not setting the source element, but the style background image.

Comment: There's a typo in Joey's suggested code. The property is `backgroundImage` and there's a missing closing quotation mark. Try this instead:  `image.style.backgroundImage = "url(image1.jpg)";`